# What is the time complexity of accessing an element of a List by index in Dart?

Tags: dart

Lists in Dart are dynamically sized unless you specify a size at creation.

So I would think the dynamically sized one would work like ArrayList in Java, and the statically sized one would work like [] in Java.

Is this correct, or is it always O(1) access? Or always O(n) access?

I haven't been able to find any resources about this online.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The runtime complexity is of course O(1).

I haven't found a list implementation in Dart core where it might be O(n) but I might have missed one.

I assume it would be O(n) for https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-collection/LinkedList-class.html

Comment: That is correct. The `List` interface doesn't say that indexing is constant time, and technically you could probably make an inefficient `List`, but the system lists are all constant-time indexable. The `LinkedList` class is just badly named since it is in fact *not* a `List`, merely an `Iterable`.

Comment: Interesting. How does Dart manage dynamically sized arrays with constant time indexing? Is it setting the size to some value larger than needed, and then allocate a new array and copy the values over when it runs out of space?